# how do i load another link if the first one is not available? in c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

i would like to load www.google.com if 127.0.0.1 is not available, how can i do this? am using C#,am a newbie in programming please help!
Here is my code

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace MyApp
{
  [Activity(Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    WebView myWebView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        myWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        myWebView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

       //my first link
        myWebView.LoadUrl("http://127.0.0.1");

        // my second link
        myWebView.LoadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in order to check the status of the first request?

Answer (score 0):

First You should write a method that checks if your server is available or not

```
    public static bool CheckIfServerIsAwake(string url)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        var reply = ping.Send(url, 60 * 1000); // 1 minute time out (in ms)
                                                        // or...
        //reply = ping.Send(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 }), 3000);
        return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
```

Than it's just decision making

```
myWebView.LoadUrl((CheckIfServerIsAwake("http://127.0.0.1") ?"http://127.0.0.1": "http://google.com"));
```